# AngularJS / $watch can't observe any string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It sounds that a `string` containing some characters like a **colon** can't be observed by angular's `$watch` function.

Here's my plunker reproducing the case (console printing the error when the html page opens):
http://plnkr.co/edit/w9ItkHZmy4khzYcWHD2A

How to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `$watch` with a string that represents a property in your scope, and not an actually object.

Just change the `$watch` to this:

```
$scope.$watch('myHourString', function (hour) {
    console.log("im ok now");
    angular.noop();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this :

```
$scope.$watch('myHourString', function (hour) {
  angular.noop();
});
```

See working plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/TE0fyZ4B9ow9pASEC9T7?p=preview)